# Finding a vector in the plane of one vector and orthogonal to another

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Given vectors **a, b,** and **p**, I am trying to find unit vector **u**, such that **u** is in the plane spanned by **a** and **p** and is orthogonal to **b**.

Assume all vectors are unit vectors

I can form 3 equations:

**u.b** = 0         (orthogonal to **b**)
**u.(a x p)** = 0   (in plane spanned by **a** and **p**)
|**u**| = 1         (unit vector)

and so solve for the components of **u**, but i was wondering if there anything more elegant?

[image]

Comment: What does it mean for a vector to be coplanar with another vector?

Comment: Given rotation about p, I want vectors a and u to be in the same plane

Comment: Any two vectors will be in some plane.

Comment: that is only if the two vector share the origin, which is not the case here

Comment: Another way to define "in the same plane" is: (a x p) . (p x u) = 1 (i.e. angle between planes defined by a,p and p,u = 0). This is another equation I could use to find u

Comment: @julianfernandez: How can two vectors not share the same origin?

Comment: in the standard definition they do, but in some case, like this, which are more like oriented segments (rather than elements of a vector space), they do not. I might be wrong, but I remember using them as an undergrad, but never used again since then.

Comment: I have edited the question to better respect the meaning of the word 'vector'.

Answer (score 2):

**u** is of the form $\lambda \textbf{a} + \mu \textbf{p}$, and $\textbf{u.b} = 0$. So $\lambda \textbf{a.b} + \mu \textbf{p.b} = 0$. This, together with the requirement that **u** is a unit vector, is enough to determine $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

A vector in the plane spanned by vectors $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf p$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf {a \times p}$.  A vector that is orthogonal to both $\mathbf b$ and $\mathbf {a \times p}$ is $\mathbf {a \times p \times b}$.  Divide by the norm to transform this to a unit vector.  $$\mathbf{u = \frac{a \times p \times b}{\lVert a \times p \times b\rVert}}$$